# jQuery: Hide div and in its place show another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this question has been asked before, but all the other answers I found are way too complicated for me to understand. 
When you click a button, I need one section to disappear and another to show in its place.

How can I do this with jQuery?

Here's the outline of my code:

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="hide">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary rounded-0 mb-2">Button</button>
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary rounded-0 btn-hide">Button</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="show mt-3">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group mb-2">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary rounded-0">Button</button></div>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

What do I need to do CSS and jQuery-wise to make this work? So the second section (.show) appears exactly where the first one was?

Comment: And where is your jQuery script? SO is not a free code service, we will help but help yourself first.

Comment: Sure, I'll post that too. I just can't seem to figure out what how to make .show appear where .hide was.

Comment: You've got a typo in <div class"hide"> it should be <div class **=** "hide">

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bind a `click` event to the button, `.show()` the section you want to show and `.hide()` the one you want to hide.

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
   $('div-to-show').show();
   $('div-to-hide').hide();
});
```

Example below:

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.hide').hide();
  $('.show').show();
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: block;
}

.show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<div class="hide">
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary rounded-0 mb-2">Button</button>
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary rounded-0 btn-hide">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="show mt-3">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, doutriforce! I'll accept your answer as soon as SO allows me!

Comment: Alright! I have added an example, so you can guide yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First, your HTML has an error in it. You have an extra closing `div` just before your closing `form`.

One of your `div` elements will default to be hidden and the other to be shown. Then upon your trigger (button click) we swap the display of both.

```js
// Get references to the two areas
var divs = $("#div1, #div2");

// When the "trigger" button is clicked, toggle the hidden class on both elements
$("#btnShowHide").on("click", function(){
  divs.toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="hidden" id="div1">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary rounded-0 mb-2">Button</button>
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary rounded-0 btn-hide">Button</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="show mt-3" id="div2">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group mb-2">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary rounded-0">Button</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <button id="btnShowHide" type="button">Click to toggle display</button>

</div>
```